# How to edit DataTemplate in VS designer

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Is it possible to edit (in design mode) DataTemplate in Visual Studio WPF Designer?.

I know its possible to edit DataTemplate in Blend throug Resources Tab.

But I couldn't find a way to open a DataTemplate in Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Yes, I've done it. What is the issue you get?

Comment: How? I dont see any resource tab (for xaml file) in visual studio

Comment: In the application resources will be maintained in different location (App.xaml, Local resources in xaml files and dedicated resource file). You can search by finding the datatemplate key or in Blend just right click on the datatemplate and select View Xaml.. it will show the xaml code in the blend and you can get the file name and location from that file.

Comment: I think it's impossible. Check notes on this sites:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546952.aspx 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907310(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but (in VS2015, at least) if you put your `DataTemplate` in `Control.Resources` and use "Go to Definition" from the context menu on a `StaticResource`/`DynamicResource` `ResourceKey` it will show that `DataTemplate` in the designer pane. The only problem is that I haven't figured out how to get back to the main control designer without closing and re-opening the document.

Comment: You can go back to the main control designer using the button "Disable Project Code" twice in the bar between designer and xaml code.

Answer (score -1):

in VS Express 2012, select your ListView or GridView, then click the property marker for "ItemTemplate" and select "Edit Resource"

this worked for me

Answer (score -1):

In VS Express 2012 it works like this:
Right click in the VS designer on your custom control/control template and select from the context menu "Edit Template" -> "Edit copy". This will copy the xaml of the control as a ressource in your active window. There you can easily edit it and e.g. see the grid lines etc.